# what is MSVC -L equivalent?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line

I'm trying to compile a library with a UNIX makefile, but using Visual Studio 2010. I modified the makefile so it should work, but I have trouble with the linker.
My compiler options are simple :

```
CSWITCHES = -O2 -I$(INC_DIR) -L$(LIB_DIR)
```

(with INC_DIR and LIB_DIR pointing to VC's include and lib directories).

I don't have include problems so I assume -I is ok, but the -L option is ignored by the compiler :

```
ignoring unknown option -Lblahblah
```

I have checked msdn site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4(v=vs.80).aspx linker options, I tried to use the LIBPATH option, but I doesn't work either.

so here is my question : what is the msvc command line option to specify a library directory path to the linker ?

Comment: Have you run vcvars32.bat before? see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: It didn't change anything. I don't think I have a path problem here. It's the -L option that is totally ignored by the compiler.

Comment: OK I make it clearer: run vcavars32.bat and include/library paths are set correctly, so you don't need to set them. `-L` option have no equivalent for msvc.

Comment: CharlesB, I set include and library path before asking my question. Since there is no -L equivalent, I removed it of my makefile anyway. I still have a problem, but I guess my question what not the good one. I have a linker error, "cannot open file libcmt.lib". I thought I had this error because the -L option was ignored.

Comment: sorry to insist but have you run vcvars32.bat

Comment: ok nevermind I'm being stupid here... i'm compiling a single source file, compiler gave me a .obj file, and that's all I need. I just didn't see that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC has no equivalent of -L option, paths are provided directly to `LINK`. As for standard library search path, it is set correctly by `vcvar32.bat` (see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Answer (score 4):

[Duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124739/visual-c-library-directories-command-line-equivalent).

You should provide /LIBPATH as a linker option, after the "/link". Assure you have cl.exe in the system path. This is my bat file for compilation:

```
call "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86

cl %CompilerFlags% ..\src\main.cpp /I %IncludePaths% /link %LinkerFlags% /LIBPATH:%LibraryPaths%
```