# Visual C++ Library Directories Command Line equivalent

Tags: c++, command-line, compilation, linker

To use some recompiled libraries (f.ex. boost chrono) i need to specify the library folder in visual studio at Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories. How can i achieve this using the command line? I have been using the /LIBPATH but i get linker error (LNK1104).

Comment: Could  you please show your command line? /LIBPATH shall work.

Comment: Here's a good source for you to start.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw(v=vs.71)

Comment: cl -I "path\to\Boost" test.cpp /LIBPATH:"C:\path\to\Boost\stage\lib"

Comment: i want to use the Boost Test Library

Comment: You need to use `/link` option to pass parameters to linker

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to specify `/link <linkoptions>` for cl.exe command line to pass the required settings to the linker:

`cl -I "path\to\Boost" test.cpp /link /LIBPATH:"C:\path\to\Boost\stage\lib"`

Comment: though, i found another problem. When i include the C:\path\to\Boost\stage\lib at VS2010, i get no errors (meaning that it found the libs etc). When i do it from the command line, it still searches for a lib that i dont have in the folder! Do you have any ideas what causes this behavior ?

Comment: Do you mean linker stops on lib that is NOT in Boost\stage\lib? Then you have to specify it with another LIBPATH option

Comment: i have created a new question for this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125049/getting-lnk1104-when-linking-to-boost-pre-compiled-libraries

Comment: @tropicana, just add `/MD` to tell the linker  you are using shared lib.