# Getting LnK1104 when linking to Boost pre-compiled libraries

Tags: c++, boost

I have built boost using the included tools and i ended up as expected with the stage/lib folder ! The lib folder contains several libraries with the following anming pattern:

libboost_*lib_name*_vc100_mt-gd-1_50.lib

libboost_*lib_name*_vc100_mt-1_50.lib

Though building a project with cl.exe i get a linker error 1104 for lib with the following pattern

libboost_*lib_name*_vc100_mt-s-1_50.lib

Any ideas ?? If on the other hand use visual studio 10 and set the stage/lib at my VC++ Direcotries - Library Direcotries, all work like a charm !

Comment: You can take a look into VS project settings, section Linker -> Command Line and see did you missed some parameters or not.

Comment: By the way, why do you need to specify all these options manually? You could build you project from command line using VS IDE - `devenv.exe /build <config name - e.g. Debug or Release> YourSolutionFileName.sln`

Comment: actually i am not using VS for my project. I used it only to test the linking (since i couldnt do it from the cmd) !

Comment: mt-s in lib name means your project is compiled with options to use multithreaded and statically linked C++ standard runtime library. Looks like your Boost build isn't configured to build such lib version, so it is missing.

Comment: fixed - my first build was only minimal and therefore some libs where missing ! Can you move the above comment into an answer ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mt-s` in lib name means your project is compiled with options to use multithreaded and statically linked C++ standard runtime library. Looks like your Boost build isn't configured to build such lib version, so it is missing.